# Kiam oni uzu "pensi" kaj "kredi"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

Kun ĉi tiaj frazoj, kiam oni uzu "pensi" kaj "kredi"?

> Mi pensas, ke ĉio estas preta por la festo

aŭ

> Mi kredas, ke ĉio estas preta por la festo

> Mi pensas, ke mi volas iri

aŭ

> Mi kredas, ke mi volas iri

Kio estas la specifaj signifoj de pensi kaj kredi?

Mi kutime aŭdas "pensi" uzate tiel ĉi, sed ĉu tio estas ĝusta aŭ eraro?

Ĉu estas alia verbo ke estas pli bona ol ambaŭ? Aŭ ĉu kaj pensi kaj kredi estas ĝustaj? Aŭ ĉu nur unu el ili?

Comment: Bonvenon ĉe [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! Plia simil-senca verbo povus esti _opinii_.

Answer (score 2):

Vortaraj difinoj de tiuj verboj ([kredi](https://vortaro.net/#kredi_kdc), [pensi](https://vortaro.net/#pensi_kdc)) povas helpi vin elekti la plej taŭgan.

Oni povus resumi la signifon de `kredi` tiel: *konsideri ion vera, sen peti/voli/postuli iun ajn pruvon*. Kiam oni kredas oni ne vere pensas aŭ analizas, oni akceptas veron.

Do tiuj ĉi frazoj

```
Mi kredas ke mi volas iri
Mi kredas ke ĉio pretas por la festo
```

estas strangaj aŭ postulas tre specifajn kuntekstojn.

`Pensi` povas rilati kaj opiniojn kaj supozojn kaj do, por la dua frazo en via demando, estus bona elekto:

```
Mi pensas/opinias/supozas ke ĉio pretas
```

Opinojn oni povas ankaŭ montri per pli simpla `laŭ mi`:

```
Laŭ mi ĉio pretas
```

Por la dua frazo, `pensi` bonas, kvankam oni povus ankaŭ uzi `senti`, `inklini`, `emi`...

```
Mi sentas ke mi volas iri
Mi pensas ke mi volas iri
Mi inklinas iri
Mi emas iri
```

Answer (score 2):

PIV donas pri "[kredi](https://vortaro.net/#kredi_kd)" kvin difinojn, kiuj ĉiuj komune havas sencon, ke oni ne postulas pruvon, simple rigardas ion kiel verdiritan. Ekzemploj (ĉiuj de Z):

- Naivulo kredas ĉiun vorton.
- Mi kredas, ke ĉiuj popoloj estas egalaj.
- Vi ne volis kredi al mi antaŭe.

"[Pensi](https://vortaro.net/#pensi_kd)" havas kvar difinojn kun pluraj subdifinoj, kiuj ĉiuj komune havas nuancon, ke oni cele aŭ intence praktikas "la kapablon, per kiu ni formas kaj kunligas ideojn". Notu, ke oni ne ĉiam povas anstataŭgi "pensi" per "kredi" kaj tial ŝanĝi de "praktiki kapablon" al "senpruve akcepti". Ekzemploj:

- Mi pensas, ke jes. (Z)
- Kion vi pensas pri mia projekto? (Kabe)

En ĉi tiu kunteksto indas mencii du aliajn verbojn.

"[Opinii](https://vortaro.net/#opinii_kd)" estas kiel "kredi", senpruve "rigardi iun aŭ ion kiel havantan ian econ". La malsimileco estas, ke oni uzas "opinii" pri eco kaj "kredi" en aliaj okazoj. Ekzemploj (ambaŭ de Z):

- Ĉiu opiniis siajn idojn la plej belaj.
- Ne opiniu vin saĝa.

"[Konjekti](https://vortaro.net/#konjekti_kd)" estas kiel "opinii", sed anstataŭ nur senpruve kredi, oni bazas sian opinion sur probablaĵoj. Ekzemploj (ambaŭ de Z):

- Petro parolas sen direkto, sed Paŭlo konjektu.
- La vidvino konjektis, ke tio estas la edzino de la pordisto.